# Find files in the folder and subfolder

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using `next if $file eq '.' $file eq '..';` to find the file in the directory and subdirectory(except few directories) and opening the files for find and replacement. But when I have dot in folder name, it consider the folder as a file and says can't open. I filtered the files using -f but it missing to show the files in the main folder.

Is there any recursive way to find the folder and files even it has dot.

```
opendir my $dh, $folder or die "can't open the directory: $!";

while ( defined( my $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ) {

    chomp $file;

    next if $file eq '.' $file eq '..';

    {
        if ( $file ne 'fp' ) {

            print "$folder\\$file";

            if ( $file =~ m/(.[^\.]*)\.([^.]+$)/ ) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget the `||` (or) in `next if $file eq '.' $file eq '..';`? It should be `next if ($file eq '.' || $file eq '..');` (albeit that doesn't solve your recursion problem).

Comment: `chomp $file;` is unneeded. The results from `readdir` do not have the trailing newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) or [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) as suggested by Sobrique.

It's very easy to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
sub process_file {
    next if (($_ eq '.') || ($_ eq '..'));
    if (-d && $_ eq 'fp'){
        $File::Find::prune = 1;
        return;
    }
    print "Directory: $_\n" if -d;
    print "File: $_\n" if -f;
    #Do search replace operations on file below
}
find(\&process_file, '/home/chankeypathak/Desktop/test.folder'); #provide list of paths as second argument.
```

I had below file structure.

```
test.folder/test.txt
test.folder/sub.folder
test.folder/sub.folder/subfile.txt
test.folder/fp
test.folder/fp/fileinsidefp.txt
```

And I got below output

```
$ perl test.pl
File: test.txt
Directory: sub.folder
File: subfile.txt
```

Comment: `File::Find` is a standard module; it comes with Perl. `File::Fins::Rule` has to installed from CPAN. For a list of standard modules, see `perldoc perlmodlib`.

Comment: along with what @shawnhcorey said, you can use `corelist` on the command line to check if a specific module is core or not: `corelist File::Find`

Comment: Just put a conditional `if(-d && $_ eq 'fp'){next;}`.

Comment: `sub process_folder {next if (($_ eq '.') || ($_ eq '..')); if(-d && $_ ne 'fp')   {print "File: $_\n" if -d;}}` nothing happening its not showing anyting if i do something like this...:-(

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Use [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm)

```
foreach my $file (  File::Find::Rule->file()->in( "." ) ) {

}
```

... and that's about it. You've got options for pretty much all the 'filetest' flags, so `file()` for `-f` or `readable()` for `-r`.